# How to add multiple rows of one linear layout into a single parent layout dynamically in program

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a row.xml file which define a row whose content and number of rows will be dynamic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/room_detail_row_in_hotel_detail">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/sz_blue"
        android:id="@+id/price"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: trying checking dynamic listview

Comment: I want to use multiple row of linear layout with a parent layout only. Because the parent layout will be inside a scroll view. I dont want to use listview with in a scroll view.

Comment: both are the same if you want to use layout to define different layout you can do the same with listview using custom adapter...google it if you think thats not the one you are looking for i will help you

Comment: @Hell Yeah, I tired doing that way but that is not I want. Dont want to use a scrollable item inside another scrollable item.

Comment: ok you dont want double scroll object and you want linearlayout so why don't you just go for simmply listview instead of using scrollview thats going to save you some time

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

You should use the Viewholder-Pattern to reuse your layouts

Comment: yes, I know this. But the question is how to reuse the xml (mentioned in the question) to create multiple linear layout within a layout.

Comment: I am new to RecyclerView I will get back after reading. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution as suggested by @Hell is to use a [Listview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).
Say you are operating within a fragment, add a listview in the xml for the same.

The fragment (or activity) containing the listview will dynamically create list(preferrable)/array of data.
In your case the dataset will essentially either be a list of class object which uniquely have two objects, price and name.

Create an adapter, could be a [BaseAdapter](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/) or any other form depending on your specific use-case. This adapter would essentially inflate your row layout (as specified in your question) and dynamically add the data.

Add the data into the adapter using it's constructor. Following which assign this adapter as the listview's adapter and call the "notify" method for the adapter indicating that a new dataset has been loaded and the list needs to be refreshed.

Also note, it's highly suggestible to  add smoothScroll to your listview for obvious reasons.